# Javascript loop on a object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to loop on a object to find what's the object name who have the socket id, and then when it's found `console.log` it
**Code:**

```
getUsernameBySocketID: function(socketid) {
    for(var User in Users.Obj) {
        var u = Users.Obj[User]; 
        if(u.socketID == socketid) {
            return u.username;
        }
    }
},
```

*EDIT:*

**`User.Obj` :** 
I add elements to user.obj with a function to create a new user:

```
Users.Obj[id] = new Users.User({username: username, socketID: socketID});
```

**and Users.User contains :**

```
User: function(data) {
    this.username = data.username;
    this.socketID = data.socketID;
},
```

but when I call the function and console.log it, it return nothing.
How can I solve that ? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. How does your `Users.Obj` look like?

Comment: Object.keys will transform the object propreties into an array, I don't want this, I want to loop on all object propreties, check if the socketID == socketid called in function, and then return it

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the current 'u' variable? maybe your condition can never become true

Comment: @MadaraUchiha edited

Comment: If it's not working you need to provide enough code that people can reproduce the problem. A bunch of undefined variables do us no good

Comment: @Watte when I console.log `u` it shows nothing

Comment: @charlietfl I've edited the post, are the codes not suffisent ?

Comment: Are you sure that 'Users.Obj' contains something? Test it with e.g. Users.Obj.length

Comment: No...we can't see any data to test against or see how function is used. Try it yourself to create a test with only what you have shown.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh, I've found my problem, thanks @Watte

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found my problem using @Watte's help
`Users.Obj` were just empty